# merge qml tags file, with lex file for presentation?

Tags: tags, qml, lexicon

I have no knowledge to qml, qt, or c++ for that part.
but my problem is that I have this .lex file, which is really only xml, and some files that end With .qml, like this one frontpagetemplate.qml.

The format in here is unknown too me.

```
<qt title="{book_name}">

<h1>{book_name}</h1>
<br/>


<!-- BEGIN paragraph_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_html_tpl -->
  {html}
  <!-- END paragraph_html_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_header_tpl -->
  <h2>{header}</h2>
  <!-- END paragraph_header_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_text_tpl -->
  <p>{text}</p>
  <!-- END paragraph_text_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_link_tpl -->
  <p><a href="{link_href}">{link_name}</a></p>
  <!-- END paragraph_link_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_olist_tpl -->
  <ol type="{list_type}">
    <!-- BEGIN olist_item_tpl -->
    <li>{text}</li>
    <!-- END olist_item_tpl -->
  </ol>
  <!-- END paragraph_olist_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_ulist_tpl -->
  <ul type="{list_type}">
    <!-- BEGIN ulist_item_tpl -->
    <li>{text}</li>
    <!-- END ulist_item_tpl -->
  </ul>
  <!-- END paragraph_ulist_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_table_tpl -->
  <table {bgcolor} {width} border="{border}" cellspacing="{cellspacing}" cellpadding="{cellpadding}">
    <!-- BEGIN table_tr_tpl -->
    <tr {bgcolor}>
      <!-- BEGIN tr_th_tpl -->
      <th {bgcolor} {width} colspan="{colspan}" rowspan="{rowspan}" align="{align}">{text}</th>
      <!-- END tr_th_tpl -->

      <!-- BEGIN tr_td_tpl -->
      <td {bgcolor} {width} colspan="{colspan}" rowspan="{rowspan}" align="{align}">{text}</td>
      <!-- END tr_td_tpl -->
    </tr>
    <!-- END table_tr_tpl -->
  </table>
  <!-- END paragraph_table_tpl -->

  <!-- BEGIN paragraph_image_tpl -->
  <p><img src="{img_src}" /></p>
  <!-- END paragraph_image_tpl -->

<!-- END paragraph_tpl -->

<table border>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">ID</th>
    <td>{book_id}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">Created</th>
    <td>{created}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">Last modified</th>
    <td>{modified}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">Publisher ID</th>
    <td>{publisher_id}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">Publisher</th>
    <td>{publisher_name}</td>
  </tr>
</table><br/>


</qt>
```

What is this syntax, is there any editor out there?
Can I convert it to html?

I really have problems finding any info on this. all I find about qml, is something that looks like JavaScript variant.

My goal is to merge these files and make a html presentation of the  tags and the data in the .lex file, rather than the ugly-looking lexion it is in today.

Answer (score 0):

The file you posted is definitely a variant on html. Hopefully someone else will recognize it right off as whatever kit it is part of. Perhaps it is rich text, perhaps some other format--but replace `qt` with `html` and you'll see it marked up in a web browser.

QML is a language that uses JavaScript style syntax for building applications. In my opinion it is a lot of fun to work with. You can download an IDE at:

http://qt-project.org/

My guess is you have a Qt Quick application that you're looking at, I'd venture a guess at Qt4 but I'm new to the toolkit so my knowledge is rather contemporary.

Comment: Heya thank you for you answer. I found what I think is the tags for this(https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html), but I kinda want to export to html from a tool, or find a editor for it. Replacing qt With html, will not help alone, because of all the {bgcolor} and such.

Comment: Take a look at a project like: http://mustache.github.io/. You can, of course, format the text using some other calls. It really depends on what you're trying to do. It is definitely a template.